# Make aliases dynamic in umbrella apps mix file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a seed file and I added it inside one of the apps mix file and it should always run before the tests. It works well from root.

```
               test: [       
                      "run apps/app_name/priv/repo/seeds.exs",
                      "test"
                     ]
```

But if i wanted to run test inside individual app it throws error because the path is now changed to this:

```
              test: [       
                      "run priv/repo/seeds.exs",
                      "test"
                    ]
```

Is there any way I can make it work from inside the app and also from root. Like may be use conditionals inside alias or something like that?

I tried defining it in the root mix file but doesn’t seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: Not related to question, but in my personal opinion, you shouldn't be seeding your test database. In my mind, tests should explicitly create needed data.

Comment: What does your root mix file look like? Playing with it on my machine seems to work. In my root file I had the `apps/app_name/priv/repo/seeds.exs`, and in my app I had `priv/repo/seeds.exs`. Beyond that, I would check that your aliases are set correctly.